# Range Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, meteor

After I updated all my Meteor packages the remove-function of my document editor doesn't work anymore. I think it's caused by this part of my code.
Meteor now runs on 1.1.0.2

What's wrong with my code?

```
return Meteor.call("removeDocument", id);
```

Comment: what's your `removeDocument` function?

Comment: That error is usually caused by something like `return Collection.find()` instead of `return Collection.find().fetch()` in a Meteor method, but in this case would seem unlikely if you're deleting a document... Without the code it's impossible to tell...

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a callback to check what is going on.

```
return Meteor.call("removeDocument", id, function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
      console.log(err);
  } else {
      console.log(result);
  }
});
```